# Android: how to change the time in emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've noticed that the time in my emulator for android projects is wrong. Its one hour behind. 
How do I go about changing the time and can I do it in eclipse?

Answer (score 6):

Run>Debug Configurations/Run Configurations

Tab Target> Additional Emulator Command Line Options

-timezone America/New_York

Answer (score 3):

I believe the emulator is set to the GMT timezone by default.  You can specify the timezone for the emulator with the `-timezone` parameter.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Answer (score 3):

use this command

```
C:\> adb shell

#date –- 2009-10-01 14:24:59

20070325.123456

#date –s 20070325.123456
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change date & time, from running emulator window go to:

```
Apps -> Settings -> Date & Time -> Disable Automatic date & time -> Set date & Set time
```

If you want to change timezone, from running emulator window go to:

```
Apps -> Settings -> Date & Time -> Disable Automatic time zone -> Select time zone
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use IntelliJ you can do that from Run/Edit Configurations window.
Go to Emulator tab and add this to "Additional command line options":

-timezone Europe/Helsinki

Android [document](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) gives this info:

> -timezone Set the timezone for the emulated device to , instead of the host's timezone.  must be specified in zoneinfo format. For example: "America/Los_Angeles"
>   "Europe/Paris"

Zoneinfo format is also known as [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). So to find you specific timezone, you can use the Wikipedia list here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 1):

Increase emulator date by some certain hours, Perfectly working
Here i am increasing time by 4 hours.

adb root
adb shell "date `date +09190400`"

Month & Date : 0919(mmdd)
hours : 04

Answer (score 0):

I have searched extensively, and it seems like the only option is to turn off the Auto-Set time in the emulator phone prefs, and manually set the timezone.  I can't find any place to set `emulator` options from inside Eclipse/AVD Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Set the time on the emulator via ADB:

Bash:

```sh
adb root
adb shell "date $(date +%m%d%H%M%G.%S)"
adb shell "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TIME_SET"
```

Powershell:

```
$currentDate = Get-Date -Format "MMddHHmmyyyy.ss" # Android's preferred format
adb root
adb shell "date $currentDate"
adb shell "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TIME_SET"
```

The `am broadcast` signal the clock to update in the status-bar, though its not needed according to my tests on emulator API-31.

The `adb root` lets following adb command execute with root-access, which is needed to set the date.

Thanks to [RipTutorial](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/16607/set-date-time-via-adb)

See also duplicate Stackoverflow with more info for special android-devices: [Set date/time using ADB shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19497572/197141)

Answer (score -1):

refer to this page
http://ysl-paradise.blogspot.com/2008/09/android.html
in the comment part.

Comment: The comments part is for actual Android app code, not for the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

The question was 9 years ago, but these days (on a mac at least) you just change your mac's time in the OSX System Preferences Date & Time pane and it's immediately mirrored in the Android emulator.