# Set date/time using ADB shell

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to set the date/time using the ADB shell but the shell only returns the current time.

I've tried:

```
adb shell date -s YYYYMMDD.HHmmss
```

and unix time like:

```
adb shell date 1318349236
```

any ideas?

Comment: First one should work. Can you write actual command (with replaced YYYYMMDD.HHmmss values) you have sent to device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run adb shell "date \`date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S\`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938791/cannot-run-adb-shell-date-date-mdhmy-s)

Answer (score 59):

To save storage space Android like many other embedded systems uses [*multi-call binaries*](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/tips0092.html) to implement its basic command line tools like `date`.

Android device may include either `toolbox` or `toybox` (or both) binary depending on the version. You can check which implementation of the `date` tool available on your device by running `toolbox date` and `toybox date` commands. Then you can use the one which prints out the current date. For example for an Android 6.0+ device it might look like:

```
$ adb shell toybox date
Mon Jul 31 21:09:28 CDT 2017

$ adb shell toolbox date
date: no such tool
```

To set date and time using `toolbox date` use `YYYYMMDD.HHmmss` format:

```
adb shell "su 0 toolbox date -s 20161231.235959"
```

In case of `toybox date` use `MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]` format:

```
adb shell "su 0 toybox date 123123592016.59"
```

Comment: make sure you have `root`

Comment: Works for me... Today was 20140222.014100

Comment: If you want to set the date to the current datem then: adb shell "su 0 date -s \`date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S\`"

Comment: It works perfectly having root thanks (make sure you allowed first shell to become root, for example allow it under SuperSU or Superuser apps).

Comment: `adb shell "su 0 toybox date $(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)"`  works well for me

Answer (score 43):

Android 6.0 has a new date format:

> ```
> Default SET format is "MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]", that's (2 digits each)
> month, day, hour (0-23), and minute. Optionally century, year, and second.
> ```

And setting with `-s` no longer works. This is the updated set command:

**Example of the updated command:**

(while inside an adb shell)

```
date 060910002016.00
```

will result in:

```
Thu Jun  9 10:00:00 GMT 2016
```

***Notice:*** The command will not be visible immediately on the device because it doesn't trigger any time change broadcast, But it will be visible within a minute.

To work around that, you can append this broadcast manually this way:

```
date 060910002016.00 ; am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TIME_SET
```

---

To call this with an `adb` command:

```
adb shell 'date 060910002016.00 ; am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TIME_SET'
```

Comment: -u means to always use UTC. To set the time in the context of the current time zone, just use "date 060910002016.00" on Marshmallow.

Comment: @tristan2468 -- thank you! corrected (removed the unneeded -u)

Comment: Thanks @uval, exactly what i needed!

Comment: I can confirm this works on Android Things devpreview 4.1 which is based on Nougat `date 081812242017.40` with root permission, otherwise error said `date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted Fri Aug 18 12:24:10 GMT 2017`

Comment: Sorry, but the new date format is somewhat weird, especially when the ISO format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS is ubiquitous. I'm wondering when they start to require seconds since the EPOCH...

Comment: @user3806649 in which scenario? This question is about ADB shell. If you can't find an answer on StackOverflow - open a dedicated question for it.

Comment: /system/bin/sh: date 060910002016.00 ; am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TIME_SET: not found

Comment: @DivyanshuKushwaha note the "(while inside an adb shell)"

Comment: @auval Thanks, the command worked without commas i.e. `adb shell date 060910002016.00 ; am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TIME_SET`

Comment: I also needed to `adb shell hwclock -w` to persist the system time to the rtc (android 8.1)

Answer (score 35):

You have to put date value if you want to change it.

`-s` changes SET format. Default SET format is `MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]`.

I successfully tested the following commands:

```
adb root
adb shell "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!

Comment: I made an alias based on this, with su 0 instead of root: ```alias adb-set-time='adb shell su 0 "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"'```

Comment: created a function instead: ```function adb-set-time { adb $@ shell su 0 "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"; }```. Usage: `adb-set-time` or `adb-set-time -e` etc

Comment: This should be set as the answer.

Comment: date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 16):

```
adb shell date -s `date +%G%m%d.%H%M%S`
```

At first it gets the current date of your machine and set it on the android target.
This approach should work on Linux/Mac/Cygwin.

Comment: Try also
`adb shell date -s "`date +'%G%m%d %H:%M:%S'`"`

Answer (score 10):

For Android 6+, To change DateTime on Emulator:

**Step 1**

```bash
adb root
```

**Step 2**

```bash
adb shell date MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]
```

For Example to set date to `Oct 29 02:01:55 2020` (or `10/29/2020 02:01:55AM`) we do this:

```bash
adb shell date 102902012020.55
```

Explanation of Date Format:

**10<sup>1</sup>29<sup>2</sup>02<sup>3</sup>01<sup>4</sup>2020<sup>5</sup>.55<sup>6</sup>**

1. Month **MM = 10**
2. Day **DD = 29**
3. Hour **hh = 02**
4. Minute **mm = 01**
5. Year **[[CC]YY] = 2020 (or can be 20)**
6. Second **[.ss] = .55**

*Year and Seconds are optional.

Comment: This was truly helpful, thanks appreciated. (y)

Answer (score 3):

To make this work on my **Xperia S**, I had to break the commands as follows:

```
> adb shell
# su -
# date /* see current date */
# date -s YYYYmmdd
```

Motive: my device had reverted to the beginning of Linux time, and I wasn't particularly worried with time, all I wanted was to set the correct date -- which, BTW I couldn't do through system settings because my custom MIUI ROM kept crashing...

Answer (score 3):

On some devices like **RTAndroid** maybe it works too:

```
adb shell "su 0 date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have any issue with Android 5, most answers I found without su in the command works.

Android 6 is the one that got my attention.
On Android 6, it didn't give me error, it just didn't set it right, it will set it back to what it was before the command. I also ran into `/system/bin/sh: su: not found errors` when I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481982/3922705
and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19497572/3922705

After all the try-and-error sessions, I figured it out.

This is the date format I use MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]

`adb shell date '0739010002017.00'`

This command didn't work, initially, in order work, it didn't work by itself.

I used this 3 steps and it works for me.

First,  `adb shell settings put global auto_time 1`

(Turn on Automatic date & time)

Second, `adb shell date '0739010002017.00'`

( set time you want )

Third, `adb shell settings put global auto_time 0`

(Turn off Automatic date & time)

> Noted:  For my specific project, I can not rely on the
>   network-provided and GPS-provided time. That's why I have the third
>   command. which turn off the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @uval's answer, you can use the following to update the date and time on the android device based on the time on your Windows machine:

```
set dateYYYY=%date:~10,4%
set dateMM=%date:~4,2%
set dateDD=%date:~7,2%
set timeHH=%time:~0,2%
set timeMM=%time:~3,2%
set timeSS=%time:~6,2%

adb shell su -c date %dateMM%%dateDD%%timeHH%%timeMM%%dateYYYY%.%timeSS%
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a android.intent.action.TIME_SET
```

Tested on a rooted Android 6.0 device and a Windows 10 PC.

Answer (score 0):

Using the other answers for the current date I get the following error:

```
date: bad date '041009502020.23'; Fri Apr 10 09:50:23 CET 2020 != Fri Apr 10 10:50:23 CEST 2020
```

Using the format `@%s` (`%s` being the UNIX timestamp) that the command accepts aswell:

```
date: bad date '041009532020.32'; Sun Apr 10 09:53:32 CET 2020 != Fri Apr 10 10:53:32 CEST 2020
```

Turns out this has something to do with timezones, specifically it seems to have to do with DST summertime (since when I replace `04` with `03` (the month) it works just fine).

The solution to this problem is to specify the `-u` option like so:

```
# toybox date -u 041009502020.23                                     
Fri Apr 10 09:50:23 UTC 2020
```

Depending on your timezone this will set the time to a slightly off value, but after you ran that command you can check with the `date` command to see how many hours you are off and simply account for that in the set date command!

Answer (score 0):

On AndroidTV API 28 simulator, this works (GNU/Linux, and some Mac) :

adb shell su root date $(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)

The host timezone should match your AndroidTV timezone.

Copy from my answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59712493/1532175

Answer (score -2):

The correct format that has worked for me is `yyyyMMddHHmm.ss`