# Cannot run adb shell "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"

Tags: react-native, shell, android-emulator, adb

I have a warning when running React Native on an Android device:

> Debugger and device times had drifted by more than 60s. Please
>   correct this by running `` adb shell "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`" `` on your
>   debugger machine

But when I run the command as suggested above, I get and operation not permitted error:

> date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted

I already tried with sudo, still got same result:

```
sudo adb shell "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I'm still finding solution for this. On mobile device it caused delay in navigation transition.

Comment: Im getting an error that says: date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted

Comment: This issue happened to me on an Android emulator, restarting it solves the problem for me.

Comment: This means that adb shell doesn't open a root shell on the phone (the error is sent by the phone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set date/time using ADB shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496907/set-date-time-using-adb-shell)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Inside the emulator goto **Settings** > **Date & Time**

1. Deselect Automatic timezone.
2. Adjust your timezone manually.
3. Deselect automatic date & time and set correct time

Comment: tried it and refreshed app (2 X shift R) - still getting that warning :(

Comment: Pay attention to the day of the month ;-)

Comment: I m not getting Date & Time in setting

Answer (score 31):

Deselecting automatic time and time zone did not work for me. Instead, I did `adb shell su root date $(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)`.

Adding "su root" is the solution to the "Operation not permitted" error.

Note that this is not equivalent to executing `adb shell` first and then `su root date $(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)` (in this case `$(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)` returns the emulator time, which is not correct, so even though the command succeeds, it does not fix the problem).

Comment: `adb shell "su 0 date \`date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S\`"`

Comment: when I try this I get `/system/bin/sh: su: not found`

Comment: omg this woked for me, all the other methods above didn't instead

Comment: `su: not found` happens when your Android device is not rooted - I think

Comment: @Andrii Chernenko How to understand ***$(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S) returns the emulator time*** in the right way?

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem in real android device, I had a time difference between the pc and the mobile higher than 60 second.
I solve the issue just by putting them on same time

Comment: Definitely a good idea to sync the clocks of the Android device and your computer's OS. Thank you, @Radhouane!

Answer (score 7):

If your phone can run `adb` as root you can use the following commands:

```
>>> adb root
restarting adbd as root

>>> adb shell "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"       
Mon Aug 26 21:04:24 +0430 201
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and solved it by enabling 'set time automatically' in windows 10 Time and Language settings. also I enabled automatic date & time in my android phone.

Answer (score 2):

The shell command seems not to work anymore. My solution is just re-starting the emulator. After restart, The date-time will be synced again. I think that the problem is because the emulator is booted from a snapshot. This kind of boot doesn't cause the time calculation incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem last week, in my case i tried:

```bash
adb root
adb shell "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`"
```

Then it's worked. Remember open the ADV first.

Answer (score 0):

After manually setting the emulator time correctly to match my MacBook's time, this issue however persists anytime, I leave the system inactive.

To deal with it, I **simply restarted the emulator, but made sure the "Set time automatically" is toggled on**. This would reset the time again to match correctly, without the need for a manual setting.