# GrantPermissionCallable: Permission: android.permission.SET_TIME cannot be granted

Tags: android, junit, android-manifest, android-support-library, android-permissions

I'm trying to use the new [GrantPermissionRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule.html) that's a part of the latest support library.

In my Manifest I declare the following:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"/>`

And in my code I call:

```
@Rule
public GrantPermissionRule mPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.SET_TIME);
```

But when I run the test I see the error:

```
12-28 14:09:35.063 7193-7215/com.blah.test E/GrantPermissionCallable: Permission: android.permission.SET_TIME cannot be granted!
12-28 14:09:35.066 7193-7215/com.blah I/TestRunner: failed: maxOfflineWithChangingDeviceTime(com.blah)
12-28 14:09:35.066 7193-7215/com.blah I/TestRunner: ----- begin exception -----
12-28 14:09:35.073 7193-7215/com.blah I/TestRunner: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions, see logcat for details
                                                                              at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
                                                                              at android.support.test.runner.permission.PermissionRequester.requestPermissions(PermissionRequester.java:110)
                                                                              at android.support.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:108)
                                                                              at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
                                                                              at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
                                                                              at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
                                                                              at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
                                                                              at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
                                                                              at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
12-28 14:09:35.073 7193-7215/com.blah I/TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
```

My build.gradle has the following lines updated:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
```

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Getting the same issue. Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @dazza5000 see my suggestion below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65914790

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SET_TIME` is [a `signature|privileged`-level permission](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml). You cannot request it at runtime, whether using `requestPermissions()` or `GrantPermissionRule`.

And, unless you are building your own firmware or are planning on your app being installed by root users on the privileged partition, you may as well remove the `<uses-permission>` element from the manifest.

Comment: So, is there anyway to change the system time at all for unit tests?

Comment: @FauxPas: Beats me. You could [try `adb`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19496907/115145) on a rooted device or emulator. Or, perhaps revise your app to allow for pluggable time sources (e.g., via dependency injection), so in your tests you can provide some controlled time source.

Comment: In order to be testable, your time-related code should use a separated class to retrieve time, that later can be mocked.

Comment: Guys, I experience same with `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: Have you declared the permission in the Manifest?

Comment: same error while requesting android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to "manipulate" the system time **if you use the emulator**.

If you **set/change the hosts system time before you start the emulator**, the emulator will take the hosts time.

This way I could, on my Windows, set the time to my desired time and then start the emulator and execute the tests.