# Can we change android mobile device date and time through automation script using appium?

Tags: android, datetime, automation, appium

In one of my automation tests, I want to update device data and time. I am using appium driver to execute the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by running [adb command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496907/set-date-time-using-adb-shell) with Appium.

Adb command:

```
adb shell 'date 060910002016.00'
```

First, try this command in terminal to see if your device allows it for you. Should be fine with emulators.

Appium provides [API](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/) to run adb command, so depending on your client library it should look similar to this (js example)

```
await driver.execute('mobile: shell',  {
    'command': 'date',
    'args': ['060910002016.00']
});
```